# How to connect oracle from unix

Tags: oracle, unix, database-connection

How to connect oracle from unix script?
I am updating one column of table emp from unix script.
for example:
table is emp.
I am updating table for the column salary where emp_id is PK.
How could i do this?
Any help guys?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to take care of the environment variables like export `ORACLE_HOME` and `PATH` etc. properly. And then invoke `SQLPLUS`.

For example,

```
#!/bin/ksh

sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
CONNECT user/password@service_name
update table set column = ....;
EXIT;
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Download [sqlplus](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) and follow [this](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-shell-scripting.php) tutorial.

A sample script would something look like so

`CONNECT user/password(@servicename if using a pluggable database) 
ALTER TABLE Emp PRIMARY KEY (emp_id)/*Or whatever updates you want here*/
EXIT;`